# RabbitMQ cluster status: how to parse Erlang's beam from a shell?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, erl, rabbitmqctl, beam

I need to monitor rabbitmq cluster status.

REST API doesn't provide information about `partitions`. So I need to use app `rabbitmqctl`:

```
# rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@rabbit-1' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@rabbit-1','rabbit@rabbit-2',
                'rabbit@rabbit-3']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@rabbit-3','rabbit@rabbit-2',
                 'rabbit@rabbit-1']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@rabbit-1">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{'rabbit@rabbit-3',[]},
          {'rabbit@rabbit-2',[nodedown]},
          {'rabbit@rabbit-1',[]}]}]
```

I need to check `{partitions,[]},`. If there is empty `[]` it [is ok](https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html). Otherwise I have problem.

I found example of use erlang from bash:

```
erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell
```

Is possible to parse `rabbitmqctl` stdout using `erl` (or other tool) and return info "empty / not empty" or return code?

I absolutely don't know Erlang.

If anyone help me, I will be happy :-)

Comment: You need to drop the first line of input since it's not part of the Erlang term, add a dot `.` at the end of the list, store that into a file and then you can read it with [`file:consult/1`](http://erldocs.com/current/kernel/file.html?i=0&search=file:consult#consult/1). The rest is data manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this `API`

`http://your_ip:15672/api/nodes`

where you can check if a node is up or down

```
name: "rabbit@t-srv-rabbit-cent04",
type: "disc",
running: false,
+cluster_links: (0)[...],
```

or partitions

```
},
-{
-partitions: (0)[
],
os_pid: "8070",
fd_total: 300000,
sockets_total: 269908,
mem_limit: 1590196633,
```

you don't need erlang shell

Comment: As an addition, you can choose to display only specific information using the following format:
`http://your_ip:15672/api/nodes?columns=name,running,cluster_links`